# Ejecutar archivo python cada 15 minutos en windows 10

Tags: python, windows

Quiero ejecutar un script de Python cada 15 minutos en windows y me gustaría realizarlo con un archivo .bat y el programador de tareas de windows, ¿cómo podría hacer esto?

[image: Esta es la imagen que sale cuando se realiza la ejecución automática en el programador de tareas]

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Ya identificaste que quieres usar el programador de tareas y tienes el script. ¿Has intentado algo para crear la tarea programada?

Comment: Siiii, mira que ya logré que intente abrirlo, pero al iniciarlo lo que hace es solicitar con qué se va a abrir(Bloc de notas, internet explorer, Python,etc) pero no sabría como hacer que se seleccione automáticamente.

Comment: Pon eso en tu pregunta. EL mensaje que sale, etc. Describe tu problema

Comment: Mira, ya coloqué lo que me muestra :(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el Programador de Tareas de Windows, Task Scheduler en ingles. Sería el equivalente a un CRON de Linux.
Este link puede ser de ayuda, así podrías ejecutar el script de Python cada cierto tiempo:

[Cómo programar tareas en Windows 10](https://www.genbeta.com/paso-a-paso/como-programar-tareas-en-windows-10)

Comment: Procura que tu respuesta sea algo más que un enlace. Si ese enlace se rompe, apagan el sitio, cambian las URL, tu respuesta ya no le servirá a nadie. Puedes poner un resumen de los pasos que indican allí. Es posible que te voten negativamente.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por el recordatorio. :)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, eso fue lo que hice pero la respuesta fue la imagen que coloqué, no sé cómo podría poner para que no se abra esa ventana donde me pide con qué abrirlo sino que simplemente se ejecute.